# Codeigniter and Ion Auth: Cannot make specific register field unique

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, ion-auth

Trying to make email field unique throws the following error: 'The Email field must contain a unique value.' But the parameter not exist and it's unique so, what's worng?

[image: error]

**The code**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|is_unique[users.email]|valid_email|required');
```

Comment: Debug! Check your post request to see if email is being received as entered, also check your 'users' table in your db for any email that matches. One of these should do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load database

```
       function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

looking for answer at same problem I found the solution on DB:

** there was a previous user registered with same email **